# Trying to use filter() to find all prime numbers in a list

Tags: python

So im trying to use filter() to find all the prime numbers in a list, but the output is weird. i been stuck on this one for like over an hour...still cant figure out where i did wrong

Here is the code:

```
TEST_LIST = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
RESULT_LIST = filter(
    lambda x: not [x % i == 0 for i in range(2, math.floor(x / 2))], TEST_LIST)
print(TEST_LIST)
print(list(RESULT_LIST))


Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What is your question? SO isn't a debugging forum.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking a question here. What about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to fix a bug with your code. You want the range to include `x / 2`, since otherwise your algorithm breaks for `x = 4`. A simple way to do this while avoiding using the `math` module is to use truncating division and just adding one: `x // 2 + 1`.

Look at the result of your list comprehension:

```
In [6]: x = 36

In [7]: [x % i == 0 for i in range(2, x // 2 + 1))]
Out[7]:
[True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False]
```

Notice that no matter the value of `x`, the list will always be non-empty. Non-empty lists are truthy, regardless of what they contain:

```
In [8]: bool([True])
Out[8]: True

In [9]: bool([False])
Out[9]: True
```

You instead want to check if any *value* of the list is truthy:

```
In [10]: any([x % i == 0 for i in range(2, x // 2 + 1)])
Out[10]: True
```

You can speed this up a little if you don't use a list comprehension and instead use a generator expression, which doesn't produce an intermediate list:

```
In [11]: any(x % i == 0 for i in range(2, x // 2 + 1))
Out[11]: True
```